# Qual é a origem de "mané"?

Tags: significado, etimologia, origem-histórica

A palavra "mané" é muito utilizada, informalmente, no Rio de Janeiro. Conheço dela dois usos: o primeiro tem o mesmo sentido de "cara" ou "gajo" (1), e o segundo é um insulto, com o significado de "bobo" ou "canalha" (2).

1. Tudo bem, mané?
2. Ele é um mané.

A partir de quando na história do Rio essa palavra passou a ser empregue em cada um dos dois casos?

Comment: Outro uso comum (que talvez tenha relação com a origem, apesar de poder afirmar isso) é o simples diminutivo do nome próprio Manoel (ou Manuel). É comum usar "Mané" como apelido para quem tem esse nome.

Comment: "Mané é um palavrão em todo lugar do Brasil. No entanto, em Florianópolis, essa palavra virou motivo de orgulho, denominando o habitante local. e um pouco comum em portugal e em algumas regiao como no fundão , mané do fundao e um ser que habita em patchachas como o da sua avo florentina o seu nome proprio e eduardo e tem um gosto peculiar por homens de rabo de cavalo." [Fonte](http://desciclopedia.org/wiki/Man%C3%A9)

Comment: "Malandro é malandro e mané é mané..." música de [Moreira da Silva](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J758GW3Bl58)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Refiro-me ao uso de "mané" na cidade do Rio de Janeiro. Para afirmar qualquer coisa a respeito de seu uso em todo o Brasil, seria necessário ter percorrido os vinte e seis estados fazendo pesquisa, com um protocolo abalizado por estatístico, ou então citar a(s) referência(s) bibliográfica(s) fidedignas.

Não posso afirmar a origem, mas recordo bem que a **gíria surgiu no início dos anos noventa**, no século passado, e discordo da afirmação de que trata-se de um palavrão. Já existia a palavra "mané" como corruptela de Manoel, há longa data e a gíria surgiu com os seguintes significados: **imbecil, idiota, otário.**

No Rio de Janeiro **mané** é pejorativo e, dependendo de com quem e como se fala, frequentemente ofensivo. No entanto está longe de ser um palavrão.

exemplos:

- **Pô, cara, tu é um mané.** (sem concordância entre pronome e verbo, comum quando se usa gíria.)
- "**Tem que ser muito mané pra fazer uma coisa dessas."**
- **"Olha só, o cara é um mané."**

Comment: Centaurus assim que referiste Manoel, lembrei que aqui, em Braga pelo menos, usamos muito "Zeca" (vem de José(Zé) Carlos) no sentido de Mané. "Então como é Zeca está tudo bem?" e "És um Zeca, para que gastaste o dinheiro todo?". Se calhar a origem de Mané pode ser idêntica.

Comment: Minha mãe é do interior do Estado de. Minas Gerais, e ela usava tanto "Zeca" quanto "Jeca" com esse propósito. Embora Jeca muitas vezes vinha também com a conotação de bruto e ignorante, também tinha o imbecil, tolo, boboca, etc. Não sei a origem do Zeca, mas Jeca creio que veio do personagem Jeca Tatu.

Answer (score 9):

***Mané*** na aceção de ’indivíduo inepto, bobo’, não é exclusivo do Rio de Janeiro. Segundo o dicionário Houaiss é comum a todo o Brasil e a regiões de Portugal. E é muito antigo, já vem atestado em [1889 no *Dicionário de Vocabulos Brazileiros* de Henrique Beaurepaire-Rohan](https://archive.org/stream/diccionariodevo00rohagoog#page/n115/mode/2up/search/guarani) (grafia original em todas as citações):

> Mané, s. m. individuo inepto, indolente, desleixado, negligente, palerma. Tambem dizem *Manécôco* e no Amazonas *Manembro*. || Etym. É apocope do termo *Manêma*, que tanto em tupi como em guarani, significa frouxo (Montoya) e mofino [desafortunado, covarde] (Voc. Braz.), o que está de accôrdo com a nossa definição. || É syn. De *Bocó* e *Bocório*, de que igualmente se usa no mesmo sentido depreciativo. || *Obs.* Ha o termo homonymo *Mané*, de que se serve a gente da plebe, como diminutivo de Manoel.

Antenor Nascente, mencionado no dicionário Houaiss, também dá *manema*, do tupi *ma’nema*, como origem de *mané*, mas por via diferente: [*manema*](http://www.aulete.com.br/manema) é farinha grossa de mandioca, e por isso de menos préstimo que a fina; daí, segundo ele, a aceção de indivíduo inepto.

Mas o Houaiss diz que outra origem possível é simplesmente o nome *Manuel*. E há boas razões a favor desta tese. Já em 1839 reinava em certos setores da sociedade brasileira a ideia que os Manuéis eram tolos, como reportado no jornal [*O Carapuceiro* (Pernambuco, 7-6-1839)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=750000&pesq=%22manueis%20s%C3%A3o%20tollos%22&pasta=ano%20183&pagfis=2496) e depois em [*O Monitor* (Rio de Janeiro, 28-8-1939)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=030740&pesq=%22manueis%20s%C3%A3o%20tollos%22&pasta=ano%20183&pagfis=986):

> Quem não terá ouvido, mórmente em companhia de Senhoras, aprovar estes, e reprovar aquelles nomes? […]
> A respeito dos homens porfião, que **os Manueis são tolos**, os Joões aparvalhados, os Cazuzas velhaquetes, os Quinquins geniosos, e já ouvi a varias Senhoras afirmarem, que a filhos seus nunca porião o nome de Francisco; por que todos são doudos, e estragados.
> […] hoje as pessoas de bom tom já não baptizão nem Chrismão seus filhos por João, Manoel, Jozé, Pedro […] porém sim por Leoncio, Rodolfo, Leovigildo, Franklim. &c. […] e tal he a mania a este respeito, que em nascendo qual quer menino, seus pais, padrinhos, ou parentes pôe-se logo a indagar, e parafusar hum nome bem extraordinário, e exquisito para lh’o darem no Baptismo;

Também em favor da origem em *Manuel* temos mais recentemente [Heinz Kröll, *Eufemismo e Disfemisno no Português Moderno* (1984), capítulo III — *Defeitos morais e mentais*, secção 1. *Estupidez e Imbecilidade*](https://www.google.pt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiTwcnJpoLLAhUM7BQKHaMFCcYQFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcvc.instituto-camoes.pt%2Fconhecer%2Fbiblioteca-digital-camoes%2Flingua-1%2F131-131%2Ffile.html&usg=AFQjCNHgnVFX1ARQJHFwB0RYVJ8LfPjfZA&bvm=bv.114733917,d.ZWU) (p. 39):

> É bastante frequente **nomes próprios de pessoas passarem a designar o estúpido**. Escolhem-se para esse fim, por via de regra, os nomes mais vulgares ou então os nomes mais raros e um tanto ridículos. Assim por exemplo: […] *joão, joão-da-horta, lopes, lucas* (provavelmente por analogia fonética com *louco* e *maluco*), *mané, manel, manécoco* (Fial[ho de Almeida, *Os*] *Gat*[*os*] V, 250:… como neste País tudo continua a estar nas mãos de dez ou doze manécocos…), *mané-jacá, mané-zé, manuel-da-horta* […] *zé-piegas, zé-quitólis, zé-da-véstia*.
>
> A mulher estúpida é chamada *amélia, bazilinha, engrácia, maria-ingélica* ou *roberta*.

A estes nomes, dos quais, com significado de imbecil, apenas alguns me são vagamente familiares, posso acrescentar [*toino*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/toino), versão popular de *António* umas gerações atrás. (O pessoal do [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/toino) deve ser bué da toino para não saber isso.) *És mesmo toino* significa ’és mesmo parvo, rústico, atrasado’.

Por sua vez [Luís da Câmara Cascudo, no seu *Dicionário do Folclore Brasileiro*, 1954](http://www.slideshare.net/edgararruda/dicionario-do-folclore-brasileiro-camara-cascudo), indica *mané* como variante de *mané gostoso*:

> [Boneco de engonço](http://artesanatosustentavel.com.br/product/mane-gostoso/), com movimentos nas pernas e braços puxados por cordões. Brinquedo infantil. Antigo personagem do bumba-meu-boi. Homem tolo, imbecil, palerma, aparvalhado, sem vontade. É um mané gostoso! O mesmo que mané-coco, mané-besta, mané-de-Sousa, pai-mané. Beaurepaire Rohan (*Vocabulário da Língua Brasileira*, RJ 1889), fixando mané, diz ser apócope de *manêma*, significando no tupi-guarani mofino, frouxo, pulsilânime. Ocorre naturalmente a apócope do português “Manuel”, dito popularmente Mané, mané-tolo, mané-bestalhão, manezinho, etc. Beaurepaire Rohan informa que *menembro* é idêntico ao mané no vale do Amazonas.

*Mané* na literatura, só consegui encontrar recentemente (é difícil encontrá-los, porque há montes de falsos positivos). *Mané gostoso* é fácil de encontrar em épocas mais antigas. O autor brasileiro Ariano Suassuna, em *Torturas de um Coração* (1951), usa-o com o significado corrente de *mané*:

> Vicentão: «O que tem aqui é moreno queimado! / Mas gente que não suporto / É esse tipo delicado e dengoso / O que é que as mulheres veem nesse mané-gostoso»
>
> Benedito: «Mas Marieta, você gostar / Dum mané-gostoso desse!»

Encontramos uma ocorrência mais antiga, com um significado um pouco mais especializado, nos [*Anais da Câmara dos Deputados* [do Brasil] — Vol 7 — p. 218 (1914)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=8xsPAQAAIAAJ&q=%22man%C3%A9-gostoso%22&dq=%22man%C3%A9-gostoso%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjR2OHcgMHKAhXBVhoKHQZgATo4PBDoAQg6MAU):

> Pois, quando todo mundo sabe que o nosso chamado Poder Legislativo não passa de um *Mané gostoso*, cujos cordões estão nas mãos do Presidente da Republica;

***Mané-coco*** encontramos já em 1830. Num artigo em [*O Cruzeiro* (Pernambuco, 15-11-1830)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=778440&pesq=mane%20coco&pasta=ano%20183), um indivíduo primeiro apelidado de  “Snr. pateta” e “pedaço d’asno” é depois apelidado de “Mané-Coco”:

> Dizem que a Santa Inquisiçaõ era tirana, naõ tinha nada de humana he verdade; mas ao menos não se viaõ tantos sicrilegios como de presente estamos vendo, e proderiaõ ser que o Snr. **Mané Coco**  naõ passasse bem em argoir os actos de Religiaõ de ignominiozos.

Esta outra passagem num artigo do [*Monitor Campista* (Campos, Rio de Janeiro, 9-8-1834)](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=030740&pesq=mane%20coco&pasta=ano%20183) não precisa de explicação:

> […] que pai de familia haverá tão bajoujo, e **Mané côco**, que deixe sua filha rapariguinha, galante, e abastada ir confessar-se a hum Clerigozinho amoladinho, e gamenho, que póde muito a seu salvo requebrar-se com ella no Confessionario, seduzil-a para cazar, e d’ali entabolar hum namoro talvez indestructivel?

Eu não conhecia nenhum destes *manés* em Portugal, mas encontrei um  *Mané-Coco* já e 1866 numa história (será que verdadeira?) de Camilo de Castelo Branco ([“Uma Epístola de Garrett e o Porto”,  em *Cavar em Ruinas*](https://archive.org/details/cavaremruinas00cast/page/46/mode/2up?q=man%C3%A9is-c%C3%B3cos)).

Depois disto tudo, a minha opinião é que a tendência para usar variantes de nomes próprios com sentido pejorativo teve quase de certeza o seu papel no surgimento, ou surgimentos, de *mané* como ’bobo’. E não tem que haver uma raiz única: o *ma’nema* tupi e o *mané gostoso* podem perfeitamente ter ajudado a fixar esse significado de *mané*

Quanto a *mané* como um termo amigável para *cara, gajo* no Rio de Janeiro, aconteceu um fenómeno semelhante na ilha de Santa Catarina, onde [*mané(zinho)* ou *mané(zinho) da ilha*](http://wp.clicrbs.com.br/cacaumenezes/2015/04/05/ilheu-e-manezinho/?topo=67,2,18,,38,77) foi adotado pelos próprios habitantes para se referirem a si mesmos.

Comment: Uau!  Bela busca, @Jacinto!  Em acréscimo, no Brasil (ou pelo menos no Rio de Janeiro com certeza), também se utiliza a expressão *zé mané* com a mesma conotação pejorativa (como em "Fulano?! Fulano é *muito* zé mané!" -- itálico sugerindo ênfase na pronúncia), à qual se pode eventualmente agregar alguma conotação afetiva quando usado ao se dirigir para alguém com quem se tenha proximidade (Como em "Fala, seu zé mané! Tudo bom contigo?").

Comment: @MarceloVentura Obrigado, eu não brinco em serviço ;) Esse *zé mané* mais me convence que *mané* vem principalmente de *Manuel*. O JorgeB também diz (comentário a outra resposta) que na zona dele (Braga) se usa *zeca* com a mesma conotação. Eu vivo uns 300 km mais a sul e nunca ouvi *zeca* usado assim. Parece que o pessoa está constantemente a criar novos apelidos jocosos a partir de nomes.

Comment: Não podemos esquecer também que na época do Brasil colônia, frequentemente os portugueses (manoéis e joaquins) eram classificados de forma pejorativa como burros, estúpidos - origem das tais "piadas de português" .

Comment: @Zuabros, fiz (já algum tempo) a tal atualização que prometi desta resposta: já em 1839 havia no Brasil a ideia de que os Manuéis eram tolos.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry my portuguese not good enough to write : Recent use of "Mané" by singer Flavia Coelho in her song "Sunshine" in this verse :
"Acendio um cigarro e pensou na mulher, sera que ta na cama com um outro mané".

Flavia Coelho biography states she is Carioca with Nordeste roots.

Here is the link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1NjXMrhP_iE

I lived in Rio de Janeiro but could not find a translation for this word then your forum helped me. Obrigado!

Comment: Welcome to Portuguese Language! If you want to ask a new question don't use this answer field to do that. You can create a new question. If it was a comment, please get a bit more rep, [and you will be able to post comments](//portuguese.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @JorgeB.To me it looks as though Chrisb3 only wanted to leave a comment, that he found here the answer to a doubt he had.

Answer (score 0):

A palavra mané é originária de África (Mandingas e outras etnias africanas do império) concretamente no império de Malí, os guardas do império são apelidados de Mané. Com a chegada dos brancos e o comércio do escravo, um bom par de número de Manés foram levados para as américas e outra parte do mundo como escravos e para citar os escravos em multidão utilizam Manés e para citar um indivíduo eles dizem Mané. Com o tempo passou a ser insulto como caso de catinga que antigamente os brancos citam como cheiro dos africanos na Senzala e agora passou a ser cheiro de quem não é asseado.

Comment: Até hoje existe milhares de pessoas com apelido de Mané em África

Answer (score -1):

Mané é o apelido dos "Manoéis ou Manuéis", nome muito utilizado em Portugal e posteriormente na colônia brasileira. O nome próprio é derivado de Emanuel, nome bíblico atribuído pelo anjo anunciador do nascimento de Jesus, que significa "Deus Conosco" ( Evangelho de Mateus, 1:23). Em hebraico: עמנואל , Deus conosco; Em latim: Emmanuel) Jesus, o Deus Conosco, mas no Brasil virou Mané.

Comment: não percebo o fim da última frase. Podes clarificar, por favor?

Answer (score -1):

Manee é a o pejorativo de maniqueista, ou seguidor de Mani. Religião perseguida pela igreja catolica dos anos 300dC em diante

Comment: Édson, bem-vindo ao "Língua Portuguesa". Em que é que te baseias para afirmar o que afirmas. Aqui neste site é importante explicar isso. Se não, qualquer um pode arranjar "explicações instantâneas": *mané* é 'o que vai com a manada' ou *mané* vem de *manietado*.