# De onde vem a gíria "migué"?

Tags: etimologia, origem, girias

No Brasil é comum, principalmente entre os jovens na internet, o uso de expressões como:

> 1) O jogador está dando migué (ou seja, fingindo que está machucado).
>   2) Aquele cara vive dando migué.

Acho que é uma palavra muito curiosa e gostaria de saber como surgiu e se é usada também em outros países.

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Migu%C3%A9

Comment: É comum?  Ouve-se diariamente no rádio e na televisão?  Seu uso é restrito a jovens?   Ou é comum entre iguais de um determinado grupo ou tribo?   De tanto ler que "xxx ou yyy é muito comum no Brasil" eu acabo me convencendo que moro em outro país.

Comment: Não sei de onde surgiu, mas é algo relacionado à "deu uma de esperto", ou "foi malandro" na sua atitude.

Comment: @Centaurus É relativamente mais comum entre jovens na internet e pessoalmente.

Comment: @BrunoLopes   Está então explicado porque eu nunca ouvi.  Já não sou jovem há muitos anos.

Comment: O "é" final rima com "vê" ou com "fé"?

Comment: @Centaurus Com "fé".

Comment: @BrunoLopes e Centaurus, obrigado pela contribuição. Editei a pergunta para: "No Brasil é comum, principalmente entre os jovens na internet, o uso de expressões como:"

Comment: Jovem no estado de São Paulo normalmente não fala "migué". O pessoal de meia idade mais "malandro" ainda fala bastante.

Comment: @eightShirt, alguém mudou o artigo da Wikipédia que tu lincaste? Ou foi brincadeira tua?

Comment: @Jacinto pelo visto mudaram.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

***Dar migué*** vem de ***dar uma de Miguel***, que tem mais ou menos os mesmos significados. Existe também ***miguelagem*** (‘falsidade, dissimulação, fingir que não sabe de nada’), ***migueloso*** e ***miguelento*** (‘falso, dissimulado’) e ***miguelar***.

Estas expressões são exclusivamente brasileiras e parecem ser todas muito recentes. *Miguelagem* é a que aparece mais cedo no Google, em 1998. Os primeiros exemplos vêm todos de ambientes prisionais ou criminais, o que sugere que a expressão possa ter tido origem no mundo do crime.

O primeiro exemplo de ***miguelagem***, juntamente com *migueloso*, com os significados de ‘falsidade’ e ‘falso’, é em *Mácula do Crime* (1998) de Everaldo Carvalho, um agente penitenciário baiano (informação obtida em [*Um estudo sobre agentes penitenciários em Salvador – BA* de Letícia Chaves Monteiro, UFB, 2013](http://www.ppgcs.ufba.br/site/db/trabalhos/2882013120944.pdf)). Logo no ano seguinte, temos *miguelagem* em [*Estação Carandiru* de Drauzio Varella (1999)](https://www.google.pt/search?q=miguelagem&num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=580&tbs=cdr:1,cd_max:2010&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3hurrnuXQAhVFI5AKHRthDzI4MhD8BQgMKAU). O livro resulta da experiência do autor como voluntário a partir de 1989 na prisão de São Paulo conhecida por Carandiru [(Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_Carandiru_(livro)). Aqui *miguelagem* parece significar ‘fingir que não sabem de nada’ (ênfase minha em todas as citações):

> De quem eram, quiseram saber os funcionários: — Os manos na maior **miguelagem**, ó. Vou dizer que não é minha? Uma que os polícias não vão acreditar, outra que eu passo por cagúeta, porque se não é minha, é deles.

O Google diz-me que tem uma ocorrência anterior, de 1996, de *miguelagem*, em [*glossary of Portuguese narcotic terms*](https://www.google.pt/search?q=miguelagem&num=50&espv=2&biw=1242&bih=580&tbs=cdr:1,cd_max:2010&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3hurrnuXQAhVFI5AKHRthDzI4MhD8BQgMKAU), mas não nos mostra nada. Ainda em 2008 na [*A Gíria Prisional*… de Maria E. T. Silva](http://repositorio.unesp.br/bitstream/handle/11449/93957/silva_met_me_arafcl.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y) vem que na cadeia *miguelagem* significa “fingir que está dormindo”, que poderia muito bem ser o que os manos na citação acima estavam fazendo. Este trabalho registra ainda *miguela* (‘sovina’), *miguelar* (‘ato de limitar algo’, “ ‘a tiazinha do hot dog tá miguelando a batatinha’ ”) e já também *dar migué*.

No Google, ***dar uma de Miguel*** aparece pela primeira vez em 2002 no [blog Celebro Eletrónico](http://celebroeletronico.blogspot.pt/2002_02_01_archive.html)

> Eu vou chutar o pau da barraca se ele continuar me enchendo o saco. Sempre que eu peço aumento de salario ele fica **dando uma de Miguel**. Ta na hora de matar a cobrar e mostrar o pau. Nao sou cu doce.

O sentido aqui parece ser ‘inventar desculpas’, o que está de acordo com *miguelento*—“pessoa cheia de desculpas sem sentido”, “pessoa que gosta de levar vantagem em tudo”— neste [*Maranhão na ponta da língua—palavras e expressões maranhenses* de José Neres e Lindalva Barros (2011)](http://files.comunidades.net/joseneres/na_ponta_da_lingua.pdf). Neste trabalho também encontramos ***migué*** e ***miguelagem:***

> **MIGUÉ**—Gíria utilizada para indicar que alguém está tentando embromar outra pessoa. Enrolação.
> *Ex.: Lá vem Janaina com seus migués pra cima da gente.*
>
> **MIGUELAGEM** – Ato de embromar alguém. Tentativa de levar vantagem sobre alguém.
> *Ex.: Não se pode confiar em César. Ele é cheio de miguelagem.*

Mas noutros exemplos, *dar uma de Miguel* significa ‘fingir não entender o que se passa’, como no [blog *memórias de sampa* (São Paulo, 2011)](http://memoriasdesampa.blogspot.pt/2011_02_01_archive.html), ou como definido explicitamente neste [Biligual dictionary of football (2014)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=YftSAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA141&lpg=PA141&dq=%22dar%20uma%20de%20miguel%22&source=bl&ots=yODrp3e4ad&sig=bjhosJupKPw18uWJyT1BEI0n9o4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwishMGByefQAhVLtxQKHUZmDhYQ6AEIOTAE#v=onepage&q=%22dar%20uma%20de%20miguel%22&f=false):

> **Dar uma de Miguel**: to ignore or behave as though you do not understand what is going on or did not comprehend what you were told. [Minha tradução: ignorar ou comportar-se como se não compreendesse o que se está a passar ou não tivesse compreendido o que lhe disseram.]

Portanto parece que *miguelagem* e *dar uma de Miguel* ou *Migué* foi tomando vários sentidos à medida que se espalhou. Há quem diga que estas expressões se inspiraram em D. Miguel, rei de Portugal de 1828 a 1834, que teria “miguelado” o irmão, Pedro I do Brasil, IV de Portugal, e a sobrinha, a futura D. Maria II de Portugal, com quem prometera casar [(Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Migu%C3%A9). Não vi uma ponta de evidência a favor desta hipótese. Parece-me plausível que algum Miguel tenha servido de inspiração a estas expressões, mas há de ter sido mais relevante na vida de quem as começou a usar do que um monarca relativamente obscuro, deposto há quase duzentos anos e morto e enterrado há cento e cinquenta.

Comment: Tenho quer ir ao registo civil mudar o meu segundo nome...

Comment: @Bruno Miguel, Bruno Miguel, ontem já era tarde! :)

Comment: @BrunoCosta - e não é que mudou mesmo...

Comment: @ANeves, mudou?!

Comment: @Jacinto. Não mudei não xD.

Comment: @sumitani, obrigado pelas correções. *Regista* não foi engano: é a forma corrente em Portugal; mas tá tudo bem.

Comment: Interessante é como alguns nomes acabaram se tornando referência para adjetivos. Da mesma forma que "Mané" (manuel) normalmente significa pessoa tola, "Migué" (miguel)  siginifica enganação, com todas as flexões e concordâncias possíveis, como miguel, miguelagem, miguelar, miguelento, miguelice...

Comment: @Zuabros, é verdade. Vê o que eu digo na minha resposta a [esta pergunta acerca da origem de *Mané*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/989/qual-%c3%a9-a-origem-de-man%c3%a9). Preciso aliás de a atualizá-la: encontrei um novo exemplo de associação de *Mané* a ’tolo’ já de 1839.

Comment: Deu o migué e não respondeu.

Answer (score 3):

A expressão "Migué" já era utilizada quando eu era adolescente, em 1985 no Rio Grande do Sul e se originou devido a um Prefeito do Interior que era impaciente e não tolerava ficar aguardando para reuniões, interrompedo-as, onde se originou a expressão "dar uma de miguel", ou seja, usar de subterfúgios para atingir um objetivo. Ver [Você conhece a origem da expressão “à moda Miguelão”?](https://gauchazh.clicrbs.com.br/cultura-e-lazer/almanaque/noticia/2018/06/voce-conhece-a-origem-da-expressao-a-moda-miguelao-cjixpbmvu0k8e01qosacs30dk.html)

Answer (score 1):

Não sei a origem mas ja utilizávamos essa expressão nos anos 90, quando eu era adolescente. Então com certeza veio antes de 1990.

Imagino que tenha sido por causa do personagem de novela da globo que se chamava Miguel e tinha essas características de ser pão-duro, vulgo mão-de-vaca. Mas não me recordo qual foi a novela.

Answer (score 1):

Dar um migué. Eu morava no interior da Paraiba, nos anos 60 e 70, minha cidade tinha muitas jaqueiras e chamavamos o talo da jaca. De migué. Enganavamos os amigos entregando o migué  e dizíamos que foi o que sobrou para ele.
Com isso migué ficou como sinônimo de enganar.

Answer (score -1):

Mas é claro que a expressão vem de história da Monarquia Brasileira. Esse xaropão aí de cima se baseia em textos da internet dos anos 90 e tem o descaramento de chamar Dom Miguel de obscuro... Acaso tudo que foi escrito no mundo, antes de 96, está na internet???
Quando Dom João VI morreu, Dom Pedro I tinha de assumir o trono português, mas ele ainda estava no Brasil e daqui não queria sair. Então, abdicou do trono português que pela linha sucessória real passou para sua filha, Maria da Glória. Como era ainda criança, deixou Dom Miguel, que estava em Portugal (irmão de Dom Pedro, tio da menina) como seu tutor e regente do trono português. Enviou Maria da Glória do Brasil para Portugal, mas depois de uns poucos meses, Dom Miguel que havia jurado mundos e fundos, proclamou-se Rei e Maria da Glória teve de fugir. Toca o Pedrão abdicar do trono brasileiro para ir combater seu irmão na Europa. Longa história, linda, mas Pedrão ganhou e Miguel foi preso e exilado de Portugal. Busquem na história pq a batalha foi grande e foi um lindo capítulo da nossa história e da de Portugal. Assim, dar uma de Miguel, é fácil de se entender. É gíria em São Paulo, capital, desde qdo tomei conhecimento dela, nos anos 60, meus avós diziam para mim....

Comment: User6892, muito bem-vindo ao site. Aqui há um sistema tal que alguém com suficiente reputação possa votar numa resposta que julgue boa. O julgamento é pessoal, mas há semelhanças, encorajadas pelo site, que seguimos, cada um a um rigor e modo. Uma das maiores é de ter **boas** referências na resposta, porquanto um pode falar à sua mercê. Jacinto deu referências consistentes, visto que assumimos que pesquisara por outros usos da expressão, porquanto ele tem ótimo histórico. Por isso, foi muito bem votada. >>

Comment: >> Em contrapartida, a tua e semelhantes respostas não têm nenhuma referência. Se nos apresentares uma referência que julguemos boa confirmando-te, provavelmente teremos uma nova resposta e, provavelmente, serás creditado.

Comment: Não vos preocupeis. É de se admirar que, se não há algo escrito, uma referência, isto não se possa ter como verdade. Uma tolice escrita há muitos anos seria indício de veracidade. Entendi bem, mas a lógica é que nenhuma gíria ganha força para atingir tanta gente sem algo importante por trás disso. Disse que foi por causa do caso de Dom Miguel, fato que entrou para a história, enquanto alguém diz que surgiu em 96, na fala de um malandro publicada num jornal.  Resta dizer o que? A verdade está aí, apesar do seu sistema de reputações.

Comment: @user6892 Boas-vindas. Pessoalmente também me surpreenderia se a expressão tivesse se originado apenas nos anos 1990; e concordo que o sistema de votos e ranqueamento por pares não é perfeito — mas essa é a base de funcionamento dessa plataforma: perguntas são postas e os votos refletem a percepção de mérito das respostas. É um trabalho coletivo em que votar é fundamental — e muitas respostas só podem ser julgadas quando acompanhadas de fontes, caso contrário não há como distinguir história de ficção plausível. Então, se a expressão é tão antiga, _deve_ haver evidência de uso anterior a 1990'.

Answer (score -1):

Dar um migué é fingir que não sabia alguma coisa pra se dar bem. Segundo meu pai já existia nos anos 50 em SP. É possível que seja bem mais antigo e tenha mesmo a ver com a "miguelada" do irmão de Dom Pedro I.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

*Migué* significa que a pessoa está enrolando, mentindo; e vem do Brasil, por exemplo  vem de Maceió, Alagoas. Lá é peculiar falar assim: “Está metendo o migué, né?”

Answer (score -2):

Migué vem do Dom Miguel de Portugal, irmão mais novo do Dom Pedro I, ele passou a parna no irmão roubando a esposa dele enquanto Dom Pedro estava no Brasil, dai vem "dar um migué"

Comment: Roubou a esposa de quem?! Essa hipótese, da origem no D. Miguel, já foi discutida noutra resposta. Como é que sabes que há algum fundo de verdade nela?

Answer (score -3):

Miguelar é mais velho que isso, e tinha a ver com não querer compartilhar algo com os amigos, especialmente comida.

Comment: Cesar, bem-vindo ao site. Isso é muito interessante, mas uma boa resposta precisa de mais pormenores e fundamentação. Como é que sabes isso? Viste nalgum livro? Se sim, indica-o. Experiência pessoal? Se sim, conta-nos: onde e quando é que ouviste *miguelar* empregado nesse sentido. "Mais velho" que isso o quê? Há anos diferentes mencionado nas outras respostas. É melhor indicar também anos ou década concreta, porque a resposta deve ser uma resposta à pergunta (que não menciona anos nenhuns), não um comentário sobre as outras respostas.